# Publishing failed in stage committing deployment

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

We did upgrade from Tridion 5.3 SP1 to Tridion 2011 SP1.

Most of the things are working fine.  Publishing of few pages is getting failed at "Committing Deployment" state with below mentioned error.  Database is SQL Server.

```
Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed, Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-249333-66560, Unable to store
item inside current transaction, Unable to persist data entity, org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException:
could not insert: [com.tridion.storage.ComponentMeta], org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could
not insert: [com.tridion.storage.ComponentMeta], Unable to persist data entity,
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.tridion.storage.ComponentMeta],
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.tridion.storage.ComponentMeta], Unable
to store item inside current transaction, Unable to persist data entity,
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.tridion.storage.ComponentMeta],
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.tridion.storage.ComponentMeta], Unable
to persist data entity, org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert:
[com.tridion.storage.ComponentMeta], org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert:
[com.tridion.storage.ComponentMeta], Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-249333-66560, Unable to store item inside
current transaction, Unable to persist data entity, org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
insert: [com.tridion.storage.ComponentMeta], org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert:
[com.tridion.storage.ComponentMeta], Unable to persist data entity,
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.tridion.storage.ComponentMeta],
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.tridion.storage.ComponentMeta], Unable
to store item inside current transaction, Unable to persist data entity,
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.tridion.storage.ComponentMeta],
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.tridion.storage.ComponentMeta], Unable
to persist data entity, org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert:
[com.tridion.storage.ComponentMeta], org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert:
[com.tridion.storage.ComponentMeta]
```

Comment: Did you use the sample cd_storage config file from the install or your old one?  Maybe try to use the sample and move your db settings and bindings into it?

Comment: Yes we used sample cd_storage config and moved our setting to it.  Most of the pages are getting published successfully. Few pages are getting failed.

Comment: We also found that when we have particular component on page, then only it is gettting failed. If we remove that component(presentation) then page is getting published successfully.

Comment: Is it possible you restored the Broker DB with an older version than the CM DB?  Then your CMS will have an item with URI 12345 for a news item but the Broker might have 12345 with a product item?  Then, when publishing, it tries to update the item but it is actually 2 different ones?  I would suggest to do another restore of your BRoker DB and CMS DB from Production (or your source system) and try again.

Comment: To restore the databases again will be costly activity. But yes, Backup of CMS, Log and Broker was taken at same time. Also we keep PR freeze while taking backup.  I do agree with you that there must be some mismatch, as we know which component is causing issue, is there any way (query) to check in broker what is going wrong for that particular component ?

Comment: How many deployer instances do you have running? Could it be there's more than one pointing to the same broker db?

Comment: We have only one deployer instance.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to remember a similar problem that was addressed by hotfix CD_2011.1.1.82946 which is available on [sdltridionworld.com](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2011_SP1_1/index.aspx). Note that this hotfix was built specially for version 2011 SP1 HR1.

Hope this helps.

Cheers,
Daniel.

Answer (score 1):

I just upgraded to Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1 and got the exact same error even after applying CD_2011.1.1.82946

Apparently, there's another hotfix (unreleased on SDL Tridion World) called CD_2011.1.1.83467 which fixed the issue